# Is SQL statement in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE parsed at run time?

Tags: oracle, parsing, plsql, dynamic-sql

Considering below procedure. For processing, it has to go through all the processing phases anyway. So my question is: Is it at this parse phase  `'Select job_id from asfd'` still treated as string and while the execution phase of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` the statement `'Select job_id from asfd'` is parsed again now as SQL statement?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_ei
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ‘select job_id from asfd’;  //line 3
END;
```

One explanation I found in [here](https://www.briefmenow.org/oracle/which-two-statements-are-correct-about-the-code-above/) is the `asdf` table does not exist but gut successfully compiled, so `'Select job_id from asfd'` is still treated as string at this stage. Any corrections please.

As matter of fact even when `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * asfd';` is replace in line 3 it still complies successfully. So I guess above explanation is correct.

Comment: some  useful information about different phases : [link]https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/A48506/sqlconce.htm

Comment: Yes, at parse time for the procedure, ‘select job_id from asfd’ is **not** parsed, it is only parsed at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. At EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, the runtime engine must first parse the statement.And i.e the reason why you cannot bind in the names of schema elements (tables, columns, etc.)

More details:
The parse phase is what guarantees that the SQL statement is properly defined. PL/SQL can tell that the following statement is valid without having to know the value of `:xyz`.

```
'UPDATE emp SET sal = :xyz'
```

But how can PL/SQL know if the following statement is well formed? We can't, and so the restriction.

```
'UPDATE emp SET :col_name = :xyz'
```